# using aws to send mail with php

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I want email to be send from my AWS server. Code works fine except sending email. Can anyone help to send email?

PHP codes :

```
 $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*_";
$password = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 8);
$password1 = sha1($password);



$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$query = "UPDATE employee SET password ='$password1' WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$subject = 'Your New Password';
$status = "";
if ($result) {
    $sender = 'no-reply@us.com.sg';

    $recipient = $email;
    $headers = "From : $sender";

    $message = "Your password is :" . $password . ". </br>"
            . "You can now login using this password</br>"
            . "Click to login <a href = 'login.php'> here.</a>";
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $status .="The password has been sent to $email.</br>Click to login <a href = 'login.php'> here.</a></br>or send another new password<a href = 'forgetPassword.php'>here</a><br/>";
} else {
    $status .="Email failed to sent to $email.Please try again<a href = 'forgetPassword.php'> here.</a>"
    ;
}
}
```

Comment: You say the code is working fine but then you say you want it to send email. So, does this code actually work or not?

Comment: There are many many related parts needed to successfully send email. Does your AWS server have an SMTP service (sendmail, postfix, exim) running? That is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please install mail package in your aws server to send email.

If your server is ubuntu, type below line in command line

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Or If you are in CentOS, try this in command line

```
yum install mailx
```

Try below line in command line of mail is sended successfully

```
echo "Message Body" | mail -s "Message Subject" yourMailId@example.com
```

Also you need to add html header to send html message. If you dont add html headers, message will be sent as plain text. So please update your program as below.

```
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*_";
$password = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 8);
$password1 = sha1($password);



$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$query = "UPDATE employee SET password ='$password1' WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$subject = 'Your New Password';
$status = "";
if ($result) {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: no-reply@us.com.sg'. "\r\n";

    $recipient = $email;

    $message = "<html><body>Your password is :" . $password . ". </br>"
            . "You can now login using this password</br>"
            . "Click to login <a href = 'login.php'> here.</a></body></html>";
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $status .="The password has been sent to $email.</br>Click to login <a href = 'login.php'> here.</a></br>or send another new password<a href = 'forgetPassword.php'>here</a><br/>";
} else {
    $status .="Email failed to sent to $email.Please try again<a href = 'forgetPassword.php'> here.</a>"
    ;
}
}
```

Comment: i think i'm using the linux server

Comment: I CentOs , i think "yum install mailx" will install mail package. Try this